# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Create a Synapse managed-private-endpoints to a Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to create a 'Synapse Managed private endpoint' to an Azure storage account via a 'Azure cli' task as a step in a pipeline. I want to create the MPE automatically.

The pipeline step calls a power-shell script with parameters. The script is located in source control. Calling the script and passing in parameter values is working fine.

Within the powershell script the following happens...

1. Get the json template (see below) from source control - this step works.

[image]

2. In the powershell script subsitute the json fields enclosed in <...> with a the parameter values passed in to the power-shell script - this works fine. The converted json is shown in the below screenshot.NB: sensitive values have been readacted here but look correct...

[image]

3. The line in the power-shell that's raising the error is...

***az synapse managed-private-endpoints create --workspace-name "$pSynapseWorkspaceName" --pe-name "$pPrivateEndpointName" --file $mpeArmJson --debug --verbose***

**I think it's to do with the json-string parmater $mpeArmJson and double-quotes - this is what I need help solving ???**

[image]

The value of $mpeArmJson which the value at this point is (note sensitive values have been readacted here but look correct)...

```
{
    "name": "dds2-datalake-endpoint",
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkResourceId": "/subscriptions/<redacted subscription id>/resourceGroups/dds2-data-tst-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/dds2datatstdlksa",
        "groupId": "dfs",
        "fqdns": [
            "<redacted-storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Azure devOps pipeline I have created a 'Azure Powershell' task. The task calls a PowerShell script stored in source-control - taking in parameters.

Inside the powershell script I am calling...

New-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint -WorkspaceName "$pSynapseWorkspaceName" -Name "$pPrivateEndpointName" -DefinitionFile "$tmpDir"

NB: the devOps pipeline runs under a Az 'service principal' which creates the Synapse workspace and in doing so gets the 'owner' and also a 'synapse admin.' permissions automatically set in IAM.

The 'service principal' also needs 'blob storage data contributor' on the main storage account linked to Synapse.